# How to set a cell in excel sheet with an image in c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to insert an image into an excel sheet using Bytescout library. But it is not happening.

My requirement is to **create a new excel file** and then **insert data including images**. I just want any kind of approach, like any Library not only Bytescout.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: See [this](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/SampleExplorer/Spreadsheet/BasicFeatures/Images), the sample demonstrates how to create a new excel file and add images to it with [GemBox.Spreadsheet](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview) library.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add images and charts into XLX/XLSX spreadsheets generated with [ByteScout Spreadsheet SDK](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutspreadsheetsdk.html) using the following code:

in Visual Basic .NET:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports Bytescout.Spreadsheet

Class Program
    Friend Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        ' Create spreadsheet
        Dim doc As New Spreadsheet()
        ' Add worksheet
        Dim worksheet As Worksheet = doc.Worksheets.Add()

        ' Put an image on the worksheet with 10 pixel margin from the top-left corner of the worksheet
        worksheet.Pictures.Add("image1.jpg", 10, 10)
        ' Put second image to 200 pixel offset and resize it to 250x200 px
        worksheet.Pictures.Add("image2.jpg", 200, 200, 250, 200)

        ' Save document
        doc.SaveAs("output.xls")

        ' Close spreadsheet
        doc.Close()

        ' Open generated XLS document in default application
        Process.Start("output.xls")

        doc.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Bytescout.Spreadsheet;
using Bytescout.Spreadsheet.MSODrawing;

namespace AddImages
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create spreadsheet
            Spreadsheet doc = new Spreadsheet();
            // Add worksheet
            Worksheet worksheet = doc.Worksheets.Add();

            // Put an image to "C3" cell
            PictureShape shape = worksheet.Pictures.Add(2, 2, "image1.jpg");

            // Make the picture "floating". It will be not moved if you move or resize the "C3" cell
            shape.PlacementType = Placement.FreeFloating;

            // Make the picture brighter
            shape.Brightness = 0.8f;

            // Put second image to "K11" cell
            shape = worksheet.Pictures.Add(10, 10, "image2.jpg");

            // Make the picture bound to the cell. It will be moved along with the "K11" cell
            shape.PlacementType = Placement.Move;

            // Crop 10% from left and right side of the image
            shape.CropFromLeft = 0.1f;
            shape.CropFromRight = 0.1f;

            // Save document
            doc.SaveAs("output.xls");

            // Close spreadsheet
            doc.Close();

            // Open generated XLS document in default application
            Process.Start("output.xls");

            doc.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

For more code samples browse [Spreadsheet SDK online documentation](https://bytescout.com/files/help/BytescoutSpreadsheetSDK/index.html) - *Advanced Examples .. * section for more source code samples covering functionality like adding images to new and existing spreadsheets, adding charts and others.